# Reload php.ini without webserver

Tags: php

i have installed php on windows just for having opportunity running php commands.

One of those commands required from me enabling few extensions (mbstring, openssl). I have enabled them in php.ini, but still it cant see it because php is not reloaded. I dont have any webservers on windows (no IIS, Apache, Nginx). How can i just reload php and php.ini without any webservers?

Thanks!

Comment: "but still it cant see it because php is not reloaded" how do you know that's the problem?

Comment: what is the problem then?

Comment: If you're just using the CLI php binary, you don't need to restart anything. If that is what you're using and you're not seeing options updated, you may well have updated the wrong php.ini.

Comment: You tell me @Tigran. You are making assumptions I am asking what they are based on.

Comment: They are based on errors, that mbstring extension is still missing

Comment: Find out what ini(s) your php uses.

Answer (score 6):

Use `php.exe --ini` to display what configuration files are being used and edit the correct php.ini file.